# Allowing user to rearrange entries in Django admin site and how to store that new custom order to survive page refresh?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-queryset

I have HTML and JavaScript in place that allows a user to move Django database entries (displayed in a table) up and down. However, is there a way that I can store this new order that the user has customized so that it will show up any time the user navigates back to that specific page view? I think get_queryset is what is causing the page (after refreshing) to switch back to the basic filtering. But, I have no good ideas on how to override it or avoid it to accomplish this task. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using ready solutions: [django-admin-sortable](https://github.com/iambrandontaylor/django-admin-sortable) or [django-admin-sortable2](http://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html). As for me, I have successfully used second solution and it works. One important note about it is to run `./manage.py reorder my_app.models.MyModel` after adding new `order` field as mentioned [here](http://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#initial-data).

Comment: I'm the author of django-admin-sortable. If your user is authenticated, you can use it anywhere in your site, not just admin :)

Comment: @Brandon Nice work :) Do you mean that this is the key difference between your app and second one? If yes then it's useful to know, thanks)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if that fork also allows use outside of admin, but basicaly as long as you're authenticated, you can call into the dynamically added admin urls from anywhere.